# Floating point multiplication in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, binary

I tried the below JavaScript in Chrome console:

```
// Case 1
0.11 * 10000 // 1100
0.14 * 10000 // 1400.000...2
// Both of 0.11 and 0.14 are infinite in binary number



// Case 2
0.14 * 10 // 1.4000...1
0.14 * 100 // 14.000...2
0.14 * 1000 // 140



// Case 3
0.14e4 // 1400
```

Can anyone explain the behaviour in each case?

Comment: This question has already been answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: The link does help a lot but it does not explain the behaviour of above cases.